# zf2 json view script

Tags: json, zend-framework2, zend-framework-routing

We are currently trying to set up routes in such a way that the returned content-type can be set using a route parameter. The routing is all working properly now, but there is one problem. If one requests html, then the normal view script is rendered. The data we provide to this script can be anything from a string to a collection of objects, and the view script decides what to show to the user.

If however JSON response is requested, then we just provide the data returned from our controller as JSON. However, some data should not be made publicly available to the user, and hence some filtering is required. Is there any possibility to use JSON view scripts (as in ZF1 with context-switch) in order to support such filtering? Or maybe another method?

Comment: can you give an example of what you mean, it' not clear..

Comment: Ok lets say in our controller we have `return ['users' => $users]` and `$users` is a collection of objects. Normally (with phtml view script) we would use only parts of these users (eg. `$user->getFullname()` and `$user->getBla()`).

If however JSON is requested, then these users are turned into JSON and even properties which should not be disclosed are visible in the response. Hence, we need some sort of view script that returns JSON, so that we can filter what properties are relevant for the current request. Hope it makes sense now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a JSON script which lets you decide what to render and what not. You have to provide the proper data in the view model such that only the data is given that is eligible to be displayed.

I have been thinking about a hook in the JSON renderer so you can filter the view model's data based on the context of the request, but such thing does not exist yet. Unfortunately, you have to select the data in your controller or model.

Comment: OK that is too bad. Thank you for this answer.